# Unable to write to external storage; Access is denied

Tags: android, storage, external

I have a class which stores images downloaded from Facebook when the app is started for the first time. What I do is that I would use a class to create a folder (if it does not exist before) and store all the images there.

**Important** I've had success on several devices of different API (all below 23). Files are written and retrieved successfully. Lately I have a new phone which uses 6.0 (API 23) and somehow the code to write files into storage system no longer works. I can no longer create the folder in the sdcard and that leads to the error.

As an added information, the phone is a rooted nexus 5X, not a external SD card. The app runs on API 23 and dangerous permission including storage is properly authorized before the app can even be used.

Using the tried and true method of getExternalStorageDirectory, which returns emulated/0/. The Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED indicates that access is granted to the storage. **The problem is the moment I try to create a folder it tells me i cannot do so.**

**.canwrite indicates that the mkdirs directory I am trying to create is not accessible**

For your reference, my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
```

My method that writes to the external storage:

```
public static String storeImage(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {
    String stored = null;
    String folder_main = "Samepage";
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    Log.i(TAG,"Storage state is " + state);
    File folder = new File(root + "/Samepage");
    Log.i(TAG, folder.toString());

    if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Storage is not mounted!");
    }

    if (folder.canWrite()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "External storage is accessible");

        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdirs();

        }
    } else 
        Log.e(TAG, "Default storage is not accessible");


    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (folder.exists()) {
        File file = new File(root, filename + ".png");
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            stored = "success";
            Log.i(TAG, "User image created successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return stored;
}
```

Comment: use [getExternalCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()). This way you will not pollute the root of the sdcard, you can remove the write permission.

Comment: try context.getExternalFilesDirs() instead

Comment: "dangerous permission including storage is properly authorized" -- you might wish to double check this. "the moment I try to create a folder it tells me i cannot do so" -- you may wish to post the entire stack trace.

Comment: you are string concatenating the root and "/xxx", which may lead to two consecutive forward slashes. Can you make sure that your concatenated path is correct?

Comment: Agree with @LeonidUsov - you're concatenating `root + "/Samepage"`. A golden rule when dealing with path strings is to check if there is a path separator already on the end - if not, add one. If you work on that principle you can always be assured there *IS* a path separator at the end and when concatenating you never need to prepend the separator to the directory or file name.

Comment: @Blackbelt 's answer is correct. I do manage to use this method to write/read successfully. However, when I try to create a folder based on the directory returned, I would still get the error that the new path cannot be accessed - Any idea? As I have a bunch of photos downloaded and it would seem very messy to not have them in one folder.

Comment: @Squonk, do you mean there is no need to add "/" in between? Because I have logged the directory and it seemed good, with only a singular / in between. Plus, it works well on other mobile that I have

Comment: did you try: `new File( getExternalCacheDir(), "Samepage").mkdir()`

Comment: Do you have the file permission enabled? In Android 6.0 you can override the manifest permissions in settings: http://phandroid.com/2015/05/29/how-to-change-app-permissions-android-m/

Comment: @StephenLau: What I meant was to check to see if there is already a '/' at the end of the path returned by any call to `getExternalStorageDirectory()` or any other similar call. There's no guarantee that all devices from all manufacturers will or will not have the trailing `/`. Check for it and if it's not there then add it. It's just a few lines of code to do that.

Comment: @Blackbelt 's answer is correct. I got it working instead of the usual getExternalStorageDirectory. Not sure why though. As for the other suggestions, I did have permission allowed and the path has only a single / in the log.

Comment: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(...) is depecratedString use this.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).toString(); instead

Answer (score 3):

On API 23+, I would suggest running this function before any external storage operation:

```
private static final int REQUESTCODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 999999999;

private static boolean storagePermitted(Activity activity) {

    Boolean readPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    Boolean writePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    if (readPermission && writePermission) {
        return true;
    }

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, REQUESTCODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
    return false;
}
```

This method requests permission to read and write to external storage and returns a true if you should perform the operation. As of API 23 external storage permissions have been disabled by default.

For further reading: [developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: what's `REQUESTCODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION`, it's failing to resolve.

Comment: `REQUESTCODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION` is an integer that you define to be used as a tag. When request permissions returns and calls `onRequestPermissionsResult` you can verify that it was the permission you requested and if it was granted.